# How can I sample uniformly from a citrus surface?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I want to sample from a [Lemon surface](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemonSurface.html) uniformly. The equation of this surface is

$$16(x^2+z^2)+(y-2)^3 y^3=0.$$

I have read the paper
[Stratified Sampling of 2-Manifolds](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=4b29674656bbf4067f23f0c24fe1b2e7ae198d7f)
. The method described in this article requires the computation of a very complex integral. Is there any other method available for uniformly sampling on such a surface?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\r}{\mathbf r}$This surface, say $S$, is naturally parametrized as follows:
\begin{equation*}
[0,2]\times[0,2\pi]\ni(y,t)\mapsto\r(y,t):=(x,y,z)=(r(y)\cos t,y,r(y)\sin t)\in S,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    r(y):=(2 - y)^{3/2} y^{3/2}/4. 
\end{equation*}
The area element is
\begin{equation*}
    dA=|\r_y\times\r_t|\,dy\,dt=r(y)s(y)\,dy\,dt, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where $\r_y$ and $\r_t$ are the partial derivatives of $\r(y,t)$ in $y$ and $t$; $\times$ denotes the cross product; $|\cdot|$ denotes the length of the vector; and $s(y):=\sqrt{1+r'(y)^2}$. (This result should be rather obvious geometrically.)

So, the coordinates $Y$ and $T$ of a random point $\r(Y,T)$ uniformly distributed on $S$ are independent random variables (r.v.'s). Moreover, the r.v. $T$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Furthermore, in this case the factor $s(y)$ in \eqref{1} is close to $1$ -- indeed, $\{s(y)\colon y\in[0,2]\}=[1,\sqrt{73}/8]=[1,1.0680\dots]$. So, the distribution of the r.v. $Y/2$ is close to the beta distribution with parameters $3/2+1,3/2+1$. So, the distribution of $Y$ can be easily simulated by the [rejection--acceptance method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling#Algorithm), with little waste. More specifically, the p.d.f. of $Y$ is
\begin{equation*}
    f=\tfrac1c\,hs,
\end{equation*}
where $h$ is the p.d.f. of $H:=2B$, $B$ is a r.v. with the beta distribution with parameters $3/2+1,3/2+1$, and $c:=\int_0^2 hs\approx1.02861$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    f\le Ch,
\end{equation*}
where $C:=\tfrac1c\,\max\limits_{[0,2]}s\approx1.03829$. Let now
\begin{equation*}
    Z:=Ch(H)U \quad\text{if}\quad Ch(H)U\le f(H),
\end{equation*}
where $U$ is a r.v. uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ which is independent of $H$ and $T$; if $Ch(H)U>f(H)$, then nothing happens and our effort goes to waste. Then the r.v. $Z$ will be equal to $Y$ in distribution. The probability of thus wasting our effort is only $C-1\approx0.03829$, or about $4\%$.

So, we have an easy and straightforward way to sample from the uniform distribution on $S$.

---

For an illustration, we have the following: $1000$ attempts were made to use the just described procedure to generate (pseudo-)random points on the "lemon" surface $S$. Exactly $4\%$ of those attempts happened to have gone to waste. Thus, $960$ (pseudo-)random points on the "lemon" surface $S$ were produced. The picture below shows the visible ones among those $960$ points on $S$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  If I understand you correctly, I'm afraid that $|\mathbb{r}_t\times \mathbb{r}_y|$ may not be $r(y)$, see [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5B3%2F8+*+y%5E0.5+*%282-y%29%5E1.5+cos%28t%29-3%2F8+*+y%5E1.5*%282-y%29%5E0.5+*cos%28t%29%2C+1%2C+3%2F8+*+y%5E0.5+*%282-y%29%5E1.5+*sin%28t%29-3%2F8+*+y%5E1.5*%282-y%29%5E0.5+sin%28t%29%5D+cross+%5B-1%2F4+*+y%5E1.5*%282-y%29%5E1.5+sin%28t%29%2C0%2C1%2F4+*+y%5E1.5*%282-y%29%5E1.5+cos%28t%29%5D)

Comment: From the geometric perspective, $dA = r(y)dydt$ appears to be correct. Perhaps some kind of symmetry with respect to y is at play here.

Comment: @haotianyi : I think $dA$ was computed correctly -- see [this Mathematica notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ipinelis/Published/Untitled-8.nb). As for your link, I don't know where your input expression came from. I suggest you re-check your calculations.

Comment: @losif Pinelis: Thank you for your thoughtful response. In your notes, you mentioned Rr, but I don't know the definition. I believe what we are concerned about is Cross[Ry,Rt], instead of Cross[Rr, Rt].

Comment: @haotianyi : You are right. This is now fixed.